# x-editable with multiple inputs group (textbox, dropdown..)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I would like to add x-editable on group of inputs like address. I want one textbox and three drop down in my code. So any one help me how to add that x-editable code?

I create code for editable field like:

```
<a href="#" class="editable_ddrfields margin-left-10" id="due_date_rule" name="due_date_rule" data-type="due_date_rule" data-clear="false" data-pk="1" data-url="update_field'; ?>">Add Rule</a>
```

Script code for that:

```
$('.editable_ddrfields').editable({
     tpl: '<div class="editable-address"><label><span>Days: </span><input type="text" name="due_date_count" id="due_date_count1" class="form-control input-small" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"></label></div>'+
         '<div class="editable-address"><label><span>Day Type: </span><select name="due_day_type" id="due_day_type1" class="form-control input-small" data-xeditable="true"><option value="days">Days</option><option value="weekdays">Weekdays</option></select></label></div>'+
         '<div class="editable-address"><label><span>Range Type: </span><select name="due_range_type" id="due_range_type1" class="form-control input-mini" data-xeditable="true" onchange="change_range_type2(this.value);"><option value="before">Before</option><option value="on">On</option><option value="after">After</option></select></label></div>'+
         '<div class="editable-address"><label><span>Date Type: </span><select name="due_date_type" id="due_date_type1" class="form-control input-mini" data-xeditable="true"><option value="1">Listing Date</option><option value="2">Expiration Date</option><option value="3">Closing Date</option><option value="4">Contingency Removal Date</option><option value="5">Contract Date</option></select></label></div>',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        $('#due_date_rule').html(newValue);
    }
});
```

Code works fine if I click on submit button, but when I clicked for edit it will not come with selected values based on database. Also I want required validation textbox based on "due_range_type" select box value.

Please help me for this issue.